# How can I sort an array using do while loop instead of for

Tags: java, sorting, do-while

Just a little something i am trying to figure out, but can't quite put my finger on it. There is something wrong with my code as it is not working as intended and not sorting properly. While i know how to achieve this with for, i am having trouble with converting it to do while.

```
String[] names= {"Kat","Bart","Adam","Tom","Marie","Alan","Ellie","Ziggy","Dan","Otto"};
    String temp="";
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
        do{
            if(names[i].compareToIgnoreCase(names[i+1])>0){
                temp=names[i];
                names[i]=names[i+1];
                names[i+1]=temp;
                i=0;
                
            }
            i++;
       }while(i<names.length-1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
```

Comment: Bogo-Sort: `do {shuffle(array); } while (!sorted(array));`.

Comment: @Johannes Kuhn i am trying to achieve sorting without using any dedicated sorting functions, something like bubble sorting

Comment: You just have to implement `shuffle` and `sorted` yourself.

Comment: you don't need to catch `NullPointerException`!

Comment: catch23 is right, but more importantly, please don't ever catch an exception without doing something in the catch clause!  at least print it.  Not doing anything will waste HOURS of your time some day--then you'll never do it again.

Comment: Sorry i just forgot to delete try catch, before i needed it and then i forgot to remove it.
@Bill K thx for advice, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {


String[] names= {"Kat","Bart","Adam","Tom","Marie","Alan","Ellie","Ziggy","Dan","Otto"};
String temp="";
int i=-1;

    do{
      i++;  if(names[i].compareToIgnoreCase(names[i+1])>0){
            temp=names[i];
            names[i]=names[i+1];
            names[i+1]=temp;
            i=-1;
            
        }
   }while(i<names.length-2);
System.out.println(names[9]);
System.out.println("Hello World!");
} }
```